# Is a self-join on a model in a django app an acceptable pattern?

Tags: python, django

Apologies if this question is too subjective.

If you are planning to close this question: please comment with a suggestion for a more appropriate place to post.

I'm super new to django and python, and I'm building a test app that keeps track of employees and who their managers are.

I would like to set up the domain model so that there there is only one list of employees, any of which can be managers, and all of which can be managed by any other employee who is designated a manager.

To achieve this, I did a self-join on the Employee model and have an "is_manager" flag to keep track of who is a manager and who isn't (see model below).

Is an acceptable pattern?

I'm worried it violates a design principle I'm not considering and there's some hairy trap that I'm walking into as a noob.

Thank you very much for your time.

models.py for the app:

```
class OrganizationTitle(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.organization_title_name)
    organization_title_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)


class ClassificationTitle(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.classification_title_name)
    classification_title_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)


class WorkingTitle(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.working_title_name)
    working_title_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)


class Category(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.category_name)
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)


class Department(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.department_name)
    department_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)


class Employee(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    org_title = models.ForeignKey(OrganizationTitle, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    manager = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    manager_email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    hire_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    classification_title = models.ForeignKey(ClassificationTitle, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    working_title = models.ForeignKey(WorkingTitle, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    email_address = models.EmailField(max_length=250, blank=False, unique=True,
                                      error_messages={'unique': 'An account with this email exist.',
                                                      'required': 'Please provide an email address.'})
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    is_substitute = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_manager = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('is_active', 'last_name',)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's perfectly fine.

I would recommend you to specify the `related_name` to keep your code more explicit:

```
manager = models.ForeignKey(..., related_name="managed_employees")
```

so then you can do something like:

```
bob.managed_employees.all()
```

---

Also, there are 2 things I would change (not your question but still regarding the models):

1.The `manager_email` field is redundant. I would remove it. You already have that information at `tom.manager.email_address` for example.

2.There are many fields that I would simply rename to `name`. For example:

```
class OrganizationTitle(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return u"{}".format(self.name)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
```

No need to call it `organization_title_name`. That's consistent with the `first_name` field (not `employee_first_name`).

Comment: Great.  Thank you so much for your expanded details on best practice.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is an acceptable pattern. This is called a "recursive relationship", or "self referential foreign keys" and is a very common usecase in realworld applications.

Here is [django's example supporting this usecase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to help on this.